# Where is the rvalue reference in this code?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I am reading this [article](https://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html) on lvalue and rvalue, and I am lost at this part:

```
class MetaData
{
public:
    MetaData (int size, const std::string& name)
        : _name( name )
        , _size( size )
    {}

    // copy constructor
    MetaData (const MetaData& other)
        : _name( other._name )
        , _size( other._size )
    {}

    // move constructor
    MetaData (MetaData&& other)
        : _name( other._name )
        , _size( other._size )
    {}

    std::string getName () const { return _name; }
    int getSize () const { return _size; }
    private:
    std::string _name;
    int _size;
};
```

And:

```
class ArrayWrapper
{
public:
    // default constructor produces a moderately sized array
    ArrayWrapper ()
        : _p_vals( new int[ 64 ] )
        , _metadata( 64, "ArrayWrapper" )
    {}

    ArrayWrapper (int n)
        : _p_vals( new int[ n ] )
        , _metadata( n, "ArrayWrapper" )
    {}

    // move constructor
    ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other)
        : _p_vals( other._p_vals  )
        , _metadata( other._metadata )
    {
        other._p_vals = NULL;
    }

    // copy constructor
    ArrayWrapper (const ArrayWrapper& other)
        : _p_vals( new int[ other._metadata.getSize() ] )
        , _metadata( other._metadata )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < _metadata.getSize(); ++i )
        {
            _p_vals[ i ] = other._p_vals[ i ];
        }
    }
    ~ArrayWrapper ()
    {
        delete [] _p_vals;
    }
private:
    int *_p_vals;
    MetaData _metadata;
};
```

The author goes on explaining:

<s>`...The reason is simple: the value of other in the move constructor--it's an rvalue reference.`</s>

I suppose he is referring to ArrayWrapper's move constructor where: `_metadata( other._metadata )` is seen.  This appears to be an lvalue to me, not an rvalue reference.

`It's an lvalue, and so the copy constructor is called, not the move constructor.`

Is he trying to say `_metadata( other._metadata )` results in the copy constructor of `Metadata` being called?

Can someone help?  TIA.

Comment: `ArrayWrapper&& other` and `MetaData&& other` in the move constructors are the rvalue references (recognizable by the `&&`). What is the confusion here?

Comment: You are correct on `he is referring to ArrayWrapper's move constructor where: _metadata( other._metadata ) is seen.`.  For your subsequent question, that's what the subsequent lines are explaining: e.g. `...But an rvalue reference is not, in fact, an rvalue. It's an lvalue...`.  Obviously `other` is a rvalue ref (it is `ArrayWrapper&& other` in the method declaration), and the author said, a rvalue ref is not a rvalue, so `other._metadata` is not a rvalue either.  Therefore you will need to use `std::move`

Comment: I previously thought he was saying `other._metadata` is an rvalue reference.   This comes from `other` is not highlighted in the original text, and was thought to be referred to the whole `_metadata( other._metadata )` chunk.  Which is why I stated `_metadata` appeared to be an lvalue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`other` is the name of a variable and therefore is a lvalue expression. Member access to a data member from a lvalue expression produces again a lvalue expression and therefore `other._metadata` is one as well.

Consequently `_metadata(other._metadata)` will call the copy constructor, not the move constructor.

The lvalue expression can be made into a rvalue (specifically xvalue) expression by a call to `std::move` in the argument expression. `std::move(other._metadata)` is a rvalue expression and the call `_metadata(std::move(other._metadata))` will prefer the move constructor overload, rather than the copy constructor.

Comment: Thank you, Mark.  It is clear now.  Btw, you say 'prefer the move ctor' ---> when does it call the move ctor?  Doesn't std::move() always force a move ctor call?

Comment: `Prefer` means that if there is an overload of a function taking a const lvalue reference and one taking a rvalue reference and the overloads are otherwise equally viable, (after applying conversions) an rvalue  as argument will call the rvalue reference version, while a lvalue as argument will call the lvalue reference version. This is not specific to the move ctors, but true for all function calls. `std::move` merely turns the lvalue (reference) into a rvalue (reference). If there was no move ctor, then the copy ctor would be called even with `std::move`.